# get name of table in repository design pattern

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I am working in project using generic repository design pattern and i need to get the name of entity(name of table) that sent to the following Add function

```
 public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity:class
 {
   public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {      
        validate("nameoftable");                 
        TEntity result= _set.Add(entity);
        return result;            
  }

 private validate(string entity-name)
 {
 if (entity-name == "students")
   {
    ////do some work
   }
 }
```

i want to get the entity table to use it for some validation before save

Comment: Okay, that's nice.  Are you just showing us your work, or do you have an actual question?

Comment: unfortunatly `entity-name` is not an option in c#, you will need to replace the - with a _. But you should really look at aspnet naming-conventions, best practise is calling parameters something like `entityName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you say like below if `TEntity` happens to be the entity or table name

```
validate(typeof(TEntity).FullName);
```

(OR)

```
validate(typeof(TEntity).Name);
```

Comment: thanks you , it's working with me but i use typeof(TEntity).Name to not include the namespace with the name